# Show if $t > 2n^2$ then $t!>(n^2)^{(t-n^2)}$

Tags: inequality

This is a small algebraic issue from part of a problem in Putnam and Beyond.

I can see than $\frac t2 >n^2$, and then that $t!>(n^2)^{\frac t2}$ but how to get $t-n^2$ in the exponent? i.e how to show the ineq which they want.

Comment: Can you show for $t=2n^2$ thatn $t!>(n^2)^{n^2}?$ Then proceed by induction on $n.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$t! = t(t-1) \cdot \ldots \cdot (n^2+1) \cdot (n^2)! > n^2 \cdot n^2 \cdot \ldots \cdot n^2 \cdot (n^2)! = (n^2)^{t-n^2} \cdot (n^2)! \geq (n^2)^{t-n^2}$$
because there are $t-n^2$ terms in this product.

Comment: Of course. I didn't think to subtract $n^2$ instead of dividing through by 2. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Induction proof. We will show that for $m\geq 1$ and $t\geq 2m$ that:

$$t!>m^{t-m}.\tag1$$

Your case is $m=n^2.$

First, for $t=2m,$ we have:

$$(2m)!\geq(m+1)(m+2)\cdots (m+m)> m^m.$$

Now, assume (1) is true for some $t\geq m,$ then using $t!>m^{t-m}$ and $t+1>2m+1>m,$ you get:

$$(t+1)!=(t+1)\cdot t!>m\cdot m^{t-m}=m^{(t+1)-m}.$$

Indeed, since $t+1> 2m,$ and a tweak of the case $t=2m,$ you get a stronger result, for $t\geq 2m,$ that:

$$t!>2^{t-2m}m^{t-m}m!$$